# Why is a winform shown different on the same 4k monitor

Tags: c#, winforms

We have a legacy .net windows forms application.
We've already replaced most of it with a web application, but still use the windows forms application for administration tasks.

When this application is used on a 4k monitor, it looks really bad, and that's understandable.

But the look changes depending of other monitors on the system.
The test is done on a lenovo 430 which has a 4k monitor connected via display port.
The resolution on the laptop monitor is 1920/1080 and on the 4k monitor its 3840/2160. The display scaling is always 200%.

All of the following screen shots were taken on the 4k monitor.

1. One test with both monitor active
2. One test with second screen only
3. One test with the notebook monitor closed (which means only one monitor available for the system)

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am aware that our application will not look good on 4k without changes and setting dpiAware/dpiAwareness.

But my question is:
Why does the applications look change only depending on which monitors are active? And is there a way to control which "kind" of look is taken?

Comment: Based on what I know, part of the reason this happens is because of how you set the Layout properties of your winforms. For example if `AutoSize` was set to `True`, every change in monitor resolution would affect the forms size. Same goes with `Anchor` & `Dock` which is why most people prefer WPF over Winforms. Without properly setting this properties, from 3840/2160 to 1920/1080 monitor you get an "abstract"(trying to make a painter joke here) winform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you are aware of this, but it was not mentioned before:

There are 3 kinds of applications:

- Not DPI aware
- System DPI aware
- Per monitor DPI aware

Details here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx

You can set the DPI-awareness on your application in app.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

and app.manifest:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

When you have a DPI >= 150% scaling can additionally controlled via
RMB (right mouse button) on the application's main file -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Scaling on high DPI

For Windows Forms the default is DPI-Scaling disables for high DPI. So everything shoud work out of the box. Maybe one of this settings is not on default? Especially the configuration in the RMB properties on the exe?

Comment: does "<add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="false" />" work for you? In 4.7.2 I still get automatically resizing

Comment: Excellent answer, and if you're like me, you might need a wee bit refresher:  RMB is right mouse button (duh), and you do this on the app's main EXE file.  That advice worked just dandy for me, especially with the Ranorex Studio App which now displays just fine on larger resolutions with >= 150% scaling set up.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft is aware of this problem and fixed it with the .Net 4.7 Framework:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/

Comment: From the 4.7 release notes: "This release includes a big set of High DPI improvements for Windows Forms DPI Aware applications". But my example is not DPI Aware at all. It just looks different depending on the seconds screen. I'll anyway test it with 4.7.

Comment: I think the most important sentence in the release notes are that Windows Forms are based on raster graphics, i personally think that in your case the scaling of 200% is playing a heavy role in why the application changes within different monitors. But thats still a guess.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, the application, that I had scaling problems with, was using [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com) components for WinForms and for WPF (simultaneously). I solved  scaling problem on 4K monitors by using [instruction](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/116666/common-features/high-dpi-support) on DevExpress' website. It seems to me that this instruction is rather general than specific to DevExpress' stuff.

Namely, I just added **app.manifest** file and replaced its default content with this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
            <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

You can add **app.manifeset** file by right-clicking project and selecting **Add New Item**:
[image]

Hope that might help you as well.